# For loop Rand sin repetir números

Tags: php, wordpress

como puedo hacer para que la variable $rand no repita los números random que muestra?

```
echo "<form action='' id='formcartas' method='GET'>";
        for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
        $rand = rand(1, 12);
        shuffle($rand);
        echo "<div id='unacarta$rand' value='$rand' name='unacarta$rand' class='unacarta'><img class='imgcartas' src='/image/'></div>"; 
        if($i == 6){echo "<br>";}  
        }
           echo "<br/>";             
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Yo llenaria un array con las cartas, e iria quitandolas a medida que las elijo aleatoriamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te paso un pequeño **script**:

**PHP**

```
$numeros_usados = array();
for($i = 1;$i <= 12;$i++){
    $rand = rand(1, 12);
    if (in_array($rand, $numeros_usados)) {
        echo 'Número ya usado' . '<br />';
    }
    else {
        array_push($numeros_usados, $rand);
        echo $rand . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Lo soluciono a través de un `array()` en el que voy almacenando los números que ya han salido. Si número aleatorio no está en ese array entonces lo pinto, en caso contrario pinto un mensaje de advertencia.

Answer (score 2):

Viendo el código en este caso podrías utilizar dos bucles uno para generar las cartas y ir revisando que no hayan salido ya y otro para la vista o impresión (aún que este es opcional),  también como recomendación  y si utilizas PHP 7 utilizar random_int()

Ejemplo:

```
$cartas = array();

    // generamos cartas
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $aleatorio = random_int(1, 12);
        // Comprobamos si ya a salido
    if (in_array($aleatorio, $cartas)) {
        // si a salido ajustamos $i y con in amos
            $i--;
            continue;
    }

        // si no a salido añadimos al array
        $cartas[] =  $aleatotio;
}

// Mostramos las cartas
foreach($cartas as $carta) {
    echo "<div id='unacarta$rand' value='$carta' name='unacarta$carta' class='unacarta'><img class='imgcartas' src='/image/'></div>";
}
```

Aun que lo anterior no tiene mucho sentido si vas a mostrar  las 12 posibilidades, es decir las 12 cartas, pues estaremos generando todas las posibilidades de un rango que ya conocemos y se pueden dar bastantes colisiones de forma que lo único que conseguiremos es relentizar el Script.

Si la idea es mostrar todo el rango 1-12 de forma desordenada y sin que se repita lo mejor seria generar todas la posibilidades y desordenar las:

Ejemplo:

```
// generas las posibilidaded
$cartas = range(1, 12);
// las desordenas 
shuffle($cartas);
// las recorres y las muestras
foreach($cartas as $carta) {
    echo "<div id='unacarta$rand' value='$carta' name='unacarta$carta' class='unacarta'><img class='imgcartas' src='/image/'></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$rand = range(1, 12);
shuffle($rand);
foreach($rand as $key=>$val) {
    echo $val." ";
    if($key==5){
       echo "indice 6 encontrado ";
    }
}
```

Hola la función `suffle()` solo sirve con array (si no me equivoco), y tu se lo estas pasando como una variable, ademas estas eligiendo un numero de forma aleatoria cada vez que corre el ciclo `for`, por lo tanto si en ningun momento almacenas este valor para luego descartarlo no te va a funcionar como quieres. Ahi te dejo un ejemplo de como yo lo aplicaria o a lo mejor no es tu idea. Espero que te sirva saludos !